# Background Image Growing As Text Inside It Does

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

my goal is to add text inside the box below which is an image and depending on how much text I enter, I would like to have the middle part of the image extend to accommodate for the increase of text inside. I do understand that one method is to "chop" the top part, a small section of the middle part, and the bottom part, and have the middle part repeat numerous times. I was wondering if someone could suggest how one goes about doing this, or, if there is a better option to take instead. Thank you in advance.

I've hosted the pictures through Flickr

Comment: The `border-image` CSS property seems to have support in modern browsers. What are your targeted platforms?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the image the background of the div then set "background-size: cover".  The image would then grow to fill the div as the div grows.